# Trails for barefoot walking near Nuremberg (Bavaria)?

Tags: germany, walking, bavaria, nuremberg, barefoot

Where are the trails adequate for barefoot walking (novices) near the Nuremberg (Franconian Switzerland, Franconian Alps)? I've noticed that most of trails in this region are partially or wholly graveled, which is very hard for barefoot novice (not to say, practically inaccessible).

I can walk a few km barefoot on ground path, but on graveled one I must give up after a few dozen meters.

Or, maybe, there are some trails specially designed for barefoot walkers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This webpage](http://www.barfusspark.info/laender/bayern.htm) has a list of specifically designated barefoot parks and paths in Bavaria.

The one closest to Nuremburg is Spalt (about 20km south), next closest is Windelsbach (about 50km east).

Wikibooks has information about a path up the [Staffelberg](http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Barfu%C3%9Fwandern%3a_Staffelberg) (about 70km north of Nuremburg), which is not specifically designed for barefoot walking, but has only one short gravel part.